# apexchart width overflows or doesn't strech

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, apexcharts

I'm using apexcharts with vue. I want the sparkline graph to take 100% of the width of it's parent.

So this is what I did:

```
<div>
  <apexchart
    :options="chartOptions"
    :series="series"
    height="150"
    style="width: 100%"
  />
</div>
```

I tried also to set the width as a prop of the component but it behaves the same.

Here are my chart options:

```
chartOptions: {
   chart: {
       type: 'area',
       sparkline: {
           enabled: true
       }
   },
   dataLabels: {
       enabled: false
   },
   stroke: {
       curve: 'straight',
       width: 3,
   },
   xaxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
   }
}
```

So nothing special here, it is copied from apex dashboard example, the only thing I've added is trying to set the width 100%.

It overflows it's parent (green) and the parent's container (yellow) as shown here:

[image]

But also when I resize the window(without refresh) it doesn't retain its size, it becomes smaller than the parent:
[image]

How can I make it fill the width of it's parent (green container) and keep it that way (responsive)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using CSS flex around the charts?

Comment: in a way. I'm using vuetify's grid. but its 3-4 level above the chart.

Comment: I figured out that the gap after resizing is due to missing data in the series and the fact that I have set a max attribute for the x axis. now after resize it takes 100% like it should but on first render it overflows.   I found this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326858/apex-charts-dont-resize-properly-when-using-flexbox but in my case there are no errors of failing to get the parent node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the gap after resizing is due to missing data in the series and the fact that I have set a max attribute for the x axis.

So that solved issue #2.

Apparently the charts render before it should, so it doesn't get the right parent's width,
a workaround that solved it for me was to not render the chart after the component is mounted.

Comment: Hi, can you show how to solved the problem? I'm using vuetify v-flex for the apexchart but facing the same problem.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue, I just removed `display: flex` on the container and that resolved the issue :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why it works, but it solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following option and it worked:

```
const chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        mounted: (chart) => {
          chart.windowResizeHandler();
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do
xaxis: {
tickPlacement: "between",
},
by defalut it is "On",

it just places you data in between so you can see a little space on left & right end of the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flex on your container and you can't stop using it try using `max-width: 100% !important;` in this container - works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For React

The following code should be given in the component in which the chart has been called.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your chart is rendering before the parent container because you have a style `display:flex` on parent container and you want to keep the display type flex then try following:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-between">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

...

<script type="text/javascript" defer>

    // Your chart options as you like it // 
    var options = [...];

    function renderchart() {
        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
    
        // This will trigger a resize event //
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }

...

// Put this somewhere in the code to call the render method //
renderchart();
</script>
```

This scaling can be visible when the chart loads but if that is not a problem then this should solve the issue of chart not taking full width available in parent container.

Answer (score -1):

```
chart: {
    width: '100%'
}
```

this might fix your issue

my issue resolved using [this method ref](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/width/)